# Where can I find a list of scopes for Google's OAuth 2.0 API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-authentication

The example I'm working with specifies the scope in the OAuth request as:
    scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile

which decodes into two URIs:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

I cannot find documentation covering the complete list of scopes that are available and what information is accessible within each scope - does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Comment: Did you ever find a good list?

Comment: @JustinThomas see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15328600/470749

Comment: the scopes in the user's questions are deprecated, the new scopes are simply profile and email

Comment: Can any one help me on this question please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220051/oauth2-restrict-to-emails-with-specfic-domain-name-using-hd-not-working/34319107#34319107

Comment: Google's OAuth2 documentation sucks.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [`Google APIs Discovery Service`](https://developers.google.com/discovery/).

A few other interesting resources:

- An [excellent blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/tips-on-using-apis-discovery-service.html) by *Nicolas Garnier* which describes the important things behind this service.
- The [Google OAuth2 playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/), is another good source of info.
- Finally if you're interested in tracking changes to the discovery documents or don't want to read all the docs, there is an interesting [online implementation](http://discovery-check.appspot.com/) by *Gerwin Sturm*.

Comment: That blog post was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: The online implementation by Gerwin is invaluable.

Comment: The Google OAuth2 playground is throwing a 404

Comment: thanks PW Kad, I have updated the url accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for this information, +1.  I would also really appreciate it if you could take a look at an unanswered question I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36289389/what-is-google-api-discovery

Answer (score 48):

Thanks to Antonio Sacco's links, I was able to find:

https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/oauth2/v2/rest?fields=auth(oauth2(scopes))

It says these are the scopes available:

```
 - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me (Know who you are on Google)
 - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email (View your email address)
 - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile (View basic information about your account)
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is a doc that was added recently to Google's OAuth 2.0 documentation, with a comprehensive list of scopes:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Comment: Thanks. This is the best answer for question. It is exactly what I was looking for (list of scopes grouped by API library). I used scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly and logically in console I enabled API called in library "Google Analytics Reporting API" but I was not able to get data from API. I had to enable API called "Analytics API". In your link I am wondered that both APIs contains analytics.readonly scope (it is misleading). I latter noticed that although scope is identical I must use correct endpoint to fetch data https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/

Comment: This is the best answer.
Thank you very much.
It's helped me a lot.

Comment: This is the answer to the actual question thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Here is the lists of all of google scopes:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Answer (score 8):

The complete list of scopes are not provided in OAuth Documentation but provided under FAQ of GData developers. The Scopes doesn't changed in change OAuth 1.0 or Oauth 2.0. The Link to the Page is Added [Click here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#AuthScopes) to know the Full List of Google Scopes or link is https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#AuthScopes

Answer (score 7):

Google's oauth docs display a table that lists all of the available scopes.

https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#scopes-table

Answer (score 4):

A little late, maybe, but this from the docs:

> For information about available login scopes, see [Login](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes) scopes. To see the available scopes for all Google APIs, visit the [APIs Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/).

Urls for those who don't like clicking on links:

- https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth#login-scopes
- https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same thing like forever and I found this really awesome tool oAuth 2.0 Playground developed by Google where you can find all scopes in various apis they provide.

Link and Chrome extension they recommend using:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

http://goo.gl/y9nH4H