# Where is doc of available scopes of Google OAuth 2.0 API?

Tags: google-api, oauth-2.0

I am looking for a list of all possible scope values for use with the Google OAuth 2.0 enabled API's, such as:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks
```

I got lost in the Google API docs and can't find a page containing such information.  Where can I find it?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a list of scopes for Google's OAuth 2.0 API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664868/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-scopes-for-googles-oauth-2-0-api)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are available on google oauth playground [Here](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/) and [here](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/). may not be full but most are available there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of all scopes in all Google api's [here](https://discovery-check.appspot.com/)

It also list which scopes each api needs to execute.