# Oauth2 restrict to emails with specific domain name using hd not working

Tags: security, authentication, grails, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

My app was restricting logins by Oauth2 to specific domain like abc.com by specifying abc.com in the hd parameter in my request .[Restrict Login Email with Google OAuth2.0 to Specific Domain Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858813/restrict-login-email-with-google-oauth2-0-to-specific-domain-name.com,but) but since these past few days its allowing anyone with a Google account login.I am sure i didn't change the code and even verified the result uri has my domain name specified in its hd parameter following this link instruction https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#hd-param .so cany any one tell me what i am doing wrong? here is my code

```
     `redirect( uri : "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?" +
            "redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&" +
            "response_type=code&" +
            "client_id="${my_client_id}"& +
            "scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email" +
            "+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&" +
            "approval_prompt=auto&" +
            "hd=apposit.com")`
```

Comment: I had the same situation, since a few weeks back the HD-parameter no longer restrict access to the specified domain. There was no change to the code, it just doesnt restrict access to the HD-parameter anymore... anyone know whats up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dont know why this is happening,but you can add a second security mechanism besides hd by checking if the user email contains `abc.com` using java's `contains()` method or **endsWith() which is more reliable** before u allow the user to go any further in Your app.

But still this is a quick fix and others with a solution should answer this question

Comment: If I were you I'd be more carefull, cause it's quit easy to ommit this mechanism, by simply making account like **abc.comHACKER@gmail.com** or **hacker@abc.com.hacker.com**.

Comment: I absolutely  agree, but as i stated above its just a quick fix and the real solution should be finding a way to make hd working.

Comment: Or you could use **endsWith()** method.

Comment: you could use a regex