# How to use Google API auth with flutter for obtaining Client-side Web Application credentials?

Tags: google-api, dart, google-oauth, flutter

I am trying to use **googleapis_auth** flutter package to obtain credentials, but stick with `var scopes = [...];` what does I need to fill in the **var scopes**

```
import "package:googleapis_auth/auth_browser.dart";

...

var id = new ClientId("....apps.googleusercontent.com", null);
var scopes = [...];

// Initialize the browser oauth2 flow functionality.
createImplicitBrowserFlow(id, scopes).then((BrowserOAuth2Flow flow) {
  flow.obtainAccessCredentialsViaUserConsent()
      .then((AccessCredentials credentials) {
    // Credentials are available in [credentials].
    ...
    flow.close();
  });
});
```

Comment: Looks like a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48477625/how-to-use-google-api-in-flutter to me

Comment: How can this question still not be answered?

Answer (score 0):

Auth scopes express the permissions you request users to authorize for your app. You can get details about what scopes you might need to add to your auth req [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664868/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-scopes-for-googles-oauth-2-0-api)

But, googleapis_auth package is meant to be used with web projects only, it can not be used in flutter project.

If you want to implement google auth, try [firebase_auth](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_auth) which allows google authentication using firebase backend.

Comment: what about if we want to login with youtube?